# Evaluating the constructor equivalent of a variable

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, wxwidgets

I have the constructor

```
class MyFrame : public wxFrame {  // defines the options on the top bar of the screen here we have:
    public:
        MyFrame();
    private:
        void OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event);  // hello option
        void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event);  // exit option
        void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);  // about option
        void OnHelp(wxCommandEvent& event); // event option

        // void OnCourseTextBoxClicked(wxCommandEvent &event);
        void OnOneHundredLevelDisplayGpButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent &event);
        void OnTwoHundredLevelDisplayGpButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent &event);
        void OnThreeHundredLevelDisplayGpButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent &event);
        void OnFourHundredLevelDisplayGpButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent &event);
        void OnFiveHundredLevelDisplayGpButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent &event);

        void OnDisplayCgpaButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent &event);

        // Common Courses equating their credit load
        /* 100 LEVEL FIRST SEMESTER */
        int CHM111 = 3;
        int CHM113 = 3;
        int MTH111 = 3;
        int MTH112 = 3;
        int PHY111 = 3;
        int PHY113 = 3;
        int GST111 = 2;
        int GST112 = 2;

        /* 100 LEVEL SECOND SEMESTER */
        int CHM122 = 3;
        int CHM124 = 3;
        int MTH123 = 3;
        int MTH125 = 3;
        int PHY109 = 2;
        int PHY124 = 4;
        int GST121 = 2;
        int GST122 = 2;
        int GST123 = 2;
        int LEVEL_TOTAL_100 = 47;
}
```

And somewhere else in the code base, some text is entered into a text box. The text box is supposed to contain one of the variables defined in the constructor which evaluate to their respective integers.

When the text box's content is evaluated e.g.:

```
course_one_text_box->GetValue();
```

evaluates
`CHM111`

I want to grab the constructor integer value for the `CHM111` which is `3`. I want to employ this value in a mathematical formula.

How do I do this?
Is there a particular syntax that grabs the constructor recorded version of the variable instead? 
Thanks.

Comment: No, there isn't. C++ does not work this way. You must write out a bunch of `if` statements, like `if (value == "CHM111") then return CHM111;`, and so on, for all other others. This is the only way that C++ works, like that. Otherwise, use a `std::map`, keyed by variable name, and then simply `return values[value];`, for all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wxTextCtrl` works with `wxString`, not with numbers.

But it's really easy to get a number from a wxString: Use [wxString::ToCLong](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_string.html#a2d7fb808fae67a4226ebeedf854a5a03). For example:

```
long value;
mystring = mytextctrl->GetValue();
if ( ! mystring.ToCLong(&value) )
    some message here, conversion failed (not a number)

//Your comparisons:
if ( value == (long)CHM111 )
   ....
```

So, if the user enters `3` the 'if' is true because `CMH111` is initialized as `3`

Notice the `(long)` cast from an `int` to avoid compiler warning. Why not use `long` instead of  `int` for the type of CHMxxx?

---

What is not possible in C++ is to compare against the **name** of a variable.

Comment: Your response didn't answer my problem but it did answer my question to a very large extent. I was able to create a map with the wxString constants and their float values. When the wxString constants are entered and evaluated by the event handler, their values (i.e their corresponding float values) are extracted and employed in a mathematical equation that gives me the correct result. Thanks for the heads up. Everything now is working as it should

Answer (score 0):

@Alvindera97,
Is your program should restrict the user to enter only those constants? Then you have a wrong tool for the job!

Look at the wxComboBox/wxChoice. This way the user will have the only choice to select from the list and you won't need to keep those constants definitions in the class.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, I would not want the users to enter the constants. The users are expected to type in the course code (in one wxTextCtrl box) and the attained grade (in another wxTextCtrl box). 

When a "Calculate GP" button is clicked, the contents of the box are gathered, checked against the enum of course codes and their credit load, map the course code to the credit load (int), map the grade to the grade point (int) and the after some rudimentary mathematical calculation based on the values of the credit load and grade point, a final value is returned....

Comment: After looking deeper at what I wanted to achieve, I decided to try C++ maps to see if I could map a course code to a credit load and a grade to a grade point to make the work easier. 

Unfortunately, this is a school project with C++. I have tons of experience with python.